# How do I load only this page when my progressive web app goes offline

Tags: javascript, python, flask, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I'm stuck on a problem: I wanted to make some tests trying to turn my simple flask web application into a progressive web application even tho I found poor information about it. This is the structure of my project:

```
│   __init__.py
│
├───blueprints
│       index.py
│       pwa.py
│       __init__.py
│
├───static
│   │   app.js
│   │   manifest.json
│   │   offline.html
│   │   sw.js
│   │
│   └───images
│       └───icons
│
└───templates
        index.html
        layout.html
        other.html
```

Where in the service worker I made this file based on Heroku's example:

app.js

```
if (!navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register("/sw.js").then(function (reg) {
        console.log("Service worker has been registered for scope: " + reg.scope);
    });
}
```

sw.js

```
self.addEventListener("install", function (event) {
    event.waitUntil(preLoad());
});

const preLoad = async function () {
    console.log("Installing web app");
    const cache = await caches.open("offline");
    console.log("caching index and important routes");
    return await cache.addAll(["/", "static/offline.html"]);
};

self.addEventListener("fetch", function (event) {
    event.respondWith(checkResponse(event.request).catch(function () {
        return returnFromCache(event.request);
    }));
    event.waitUntil(addToCache(event.request));
});

const checkResponse = function (request) {
    return new Promise(function (fulfill, reject) {
        fetch(request).then(function (response) {
            if (response.status !== 404) {
                fulfill(response);
            } else {
                reject();
            }
        }, reject);
    });
};

const addToCache = async function (request) {
    const cache = await caches.open("offline");
    const response = await fetch(request);
    console.log(response.url + " was cached");
    return await cache.put(request, response);
};

const returnFromCache = async function (request) {
    const cache = await caches.open("offline");
    const matching = await cache.match(request);
    if (!matching || matching.status === 404) {
        return cache.match("offline.html");
    } else {
        return matching;
    }
};
```

Yet I don't understand why if I go offline and try to reload either the web app or the PWA, only the index is loaded whereas I just want to load the offline template page, thus I think it to be cached, to load

Answer (score 0):

There's an example of creating a dedicated offline fallback page in [this post](https://web.dev/offline-fallback-page/).

If *all* you care about is showing an offline fallback page, the main important point is to ensure that you only trigger your fallback logic and call `event.respondWith()` if the `fetch` handler is dealing with a navigation request. Here's a relevant snippet of code from that post:

```js
// Incrementing OFFLINE_VERSION will kick off the install event and force
// previously cached resources to be updated from the network.
// This variable is intentionally declared and unused.
const OFFLINE_VERSION = 1;
const CACHE_NAME = "offline";
// Customize this with a different URL if needed.
const OFFLINE_URL = "offline.html";

self.addEventListener("install", (event) => {
  event.waitUntil(
    (async () => {
      const cache = await caches.open(CACHE_NAME);
      // Setting {cache: 'reload'} in the new request will ensure that the
      // response isn't fulfilled from the HTTP cache; i.e., it will be from
      // the network.
      await cache.add(new Request(OFFLINE_URL, { cache: "reload" }));
    })()
  );
  // Force the waiting service worker to become the active service worker.
  self.skipWaiting();
});

self.addEventListener("activate", (event) => {
  event.waitUntil(
    (async () => {
      // Enable navigation preload if it's supported.
      // See https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/02/navigation-preload
      if ("navigationPreload" in self.registration) {
        await self.registration.navigationPreload.enable();
      }
    })()
  );

  // Tell the active service worker to take control of the page immediately.
  self.clients.claim();
});

self.addEventListener("fetch", (event) => {
  // We only want to call event.respondWith() if this is a navigation request
  // for an HTML page.
  if (event.request.mode === "navigate") {
    event.respondWith(
      (async () => {
        try {
          // First, try to use the navigation preload response if it's supported.
          const preloadResponse = await event.preloadResponse;
          if (preloadResponse) {
            return preloadResponse;
          }

          // Always try the network first.
          const networkResponse = await fetch(event.request);
          return networkResponse;
        } catch (error) {
          // catch is only triggered if an exception is thrown, which is likely
          // due to a network error.
          // If fetch() returns a valid HTTP response with a response code in
          // the 4xx or 5xx range, the catch() will NOT be called.
          console.log("Fetch failed; returning offline page instead.", error);

          const cache = await caches.open(CACHE_NAME);
          const cachedResponse = await cache.match(OFFLINE_URL);
          return cachedResponse;
        }
      })()
    );
  }

  // If our if() condition is false, then this fetch handler won't intercept the
  // request. If there are any other fetch handlers registered, they will get a
  // chance to call event.respondWith(). If no fetch handlers call
  // event.respondWith(), the request will be handled by the browser as if there
  // were no service worker involvement.
});
```